# How did some generic names get registered as trademark?

Tags: legal-terms

Even through general names cannot be trademark (according to my limited knowledge) but Amazon and apple are already trademarks. Can someone explain this to me.

Comment: Occam's razor: your assumption that common words cannot be registered as trademarks is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

General words can be trademarked, but they have to be distinctive in the context of the business trademarking them - and the trademark restriction generally only applies to people trying to set up a competing business.

So if you were in the business of selling actual apples, you couldn't trademark the word apple. It isn't distinctive in that context. But Apple Computer was able to trademark the word apple for the business of selling computers - in that context it distinctively identifies one company.

Similarly if you were in the business specifically of selling tours of the Amazon Rainforest you probably couldn't trademark the word Amazon. But in online book retail, and the other categories that Amazon expanded to, the word is distinctive enough that they were able to trademark it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a trademark for a specific area. For example, Amazon has a trademark but that doesn't cover all uses. If you wrote a book "My adventures on the Amazon river", or you organise Amazon river cruises, the Amazon company cannot stop you. If you created "Amazon cake deliveries" they would most likely stop you.

It may be more difficult to get a trademark for a generic name, and it may be harder to protect it, but it's not impossible.